# Mirror synchronization of local folders with google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, synchronization, backup

I want to synchronize some local folders from my desktop to my Google Drive account. I have to mention that I have more than 2 million files totalizing 1 To and file sizes are from 1o to 100 Go (a zip archive).

Using drive for desktop, the google application for the synchronization, takes years since each time this app is opened, it is checking all the files. Considering the number of files I have, you understand that it is quite long. Additionally, I have the feeling that only 3 files can be simultaneously uploaded on the drive with this "Google Drive for desktop" app.

I am looking for an alternative solution that would allow me to save my local folder in a "mirror" way. I mean that, when modifications are performed in my local folder on my computer, they are pushed to my google drive in real-time.

Do you know about such a free software I could use, that would not take years in an infinite checking loop before synchronizing my files?

Answer (score 0):

I use Viper FTP for Mac for a similar task. There you can define what they call an "observed folder" - a folder that is watched by ViperFTP and if any modifications are detected, new / modified files are uploaded to the defined server (s). The app also supports Google Drive.